# .NET Serial over TCP Class

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port, sensors, modbus

Firstly I'm Autistic and this is my first post, so please. Also I'm not too sure how to phrase the question, so I'll describe the scenario and perhaps you can help me.

I have a Serial Device server (Moxa Nport DE308). It has 8 RS232 level ports, and I have it configured as a TCP server. The TCP Ports match the actual ports from 4001 to 4008. But there is no SDK, no library.

We have a variety of equipment connected to it, from screens to airconditioning. So I wrote it a class using sockets, and then I reference it in another class for each bit of kit.

Whilst it works, I have a fundamental question. And I don't know how to word it.. I'll describe what I've done (sorry about this) Let's go with the Aircon class

Here is the Class that does the talking

---

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading

Public Class MoxaSerialPort

    Private Client As TcpClient
    Private DataStream As NetworkStream

    Private Nlock As System.Object = New System.Object

    Public Property NoResponse As Boolean = False
    Public Property Delay As Integer = 180

    Private Port As Integer

    Public Sub Open(ByVal MoxaIPAddress As String, ByVal MoxaTCPPort As Integer)

        If Ping(MoxaIPAddress) Then

            Client = New TcpClient(MoxaIPAddress, MoxaTCPPort)
            DataStream = Client.GetStream

            Port = MoxaTCPPort

        Else

            Throw New IO.IOException("Destination Host Unavailable " & MoxaIPAddress)

        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()

        If DataStream IsNot Nothing Then
            DataStream.Flush()
            DataStream.Close()
            DataStream.Dispose()
            DataStream = Nothing
        End If

        If Client IsNot Nothing Then
            If Client.Connected Then
                Client.Close()
                Client.Dispose()
            End If
            Client = Nothing
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function Ping(address As String) As Boolean

        Return My.Computer.Network.Ping(address)

    End Function

    Public Function ParseCommand(Command As Byte(), Optional Retries As Integer = 3) As Byte()

        Dim ReadBuffer() As Byte, Attempts As Integer

        If (Client IsNot Nothing) AndAlso Client.Connected Then

            Do

                SyncLock (Nlock)

                    DataStream.Write(Command, 0, Command.Count)
                    DataStream.Flush()

                    Thread.Sleep(Delay)

                    If DataStream.CanRead AndAlso Client.Available > 0 Then

                        ReDim ReadBuffer(Client.Available)
                        DataStream.Read(ReadBuffer, 0, Client.Available)
                        DataStream.Flush()

                        Return ReadBuffer

                    End If

                End SyncLock

                If NoResponse = True Then Return Nothing        'not expecting or don't care about response.

                Thread.Sleep(750)
                Attempts = Attempts + 1
                Debug.Print("Attempt " & Attempts.ToString)

            Loop While DataStream.CanWrite AndAlso Attempts < Retries

            Throw New IO.IOException("No response after {0} attempts.", Attempts)

        Else

            Throw New IO.IOException("Connection failed.")

        End If

        Return Nothing

    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property Connected As Boolean

        Get

            If Client IsNot Nothing Then Return Client.Connected
            Return False

        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

---

I'm trying to use this class in individual classes for each bit of gear connected eg. aircon.

But just checking every x isn't good.
Do I put a timer in the class and have it constantly update.?
Do I do the above, raise events and then update the form.?
How many times can I pool the thing.?

Here's the form update for the aircon..

---

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class AirconTab

    Private Shared AirconUpdateTimer As Timer

    Shared Sub TimerInit()

        Dim AirconCallBack As New TimerCallback(AddressOf AirconTab.UpdateAirconForm)
        AirconUpdateTimer = New Timer(AirconCallBack, Nothing, 0, Timeout.Infinite)

    End Sub

    Shared Sub UpdateAirconForm()

        Try

            If Aircon.ClientActive Then

                Update()

            Else

                TimerStop()

                Dim SelectedOption As Integer = MsgBox("Connection to 10.10.10.12:4002 has been lost. Reconnect..?", vbOKCancel Or vbExclamation, "AirconTab.UpdateAirconForm")

                If SelectedOption = MsgBoxResult.Ok AndAlso Aircon.Connect = True Then TimerStart()

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            Debug.Print(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub Update()

        If frmMain.MainFormInstance IsNot Nothing Then

            With frmMain.MainFormInstance

                If .InvokeRequired Then
                    .Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Update))

                Else

                    Try

                        Dim Registers As Integer() = Aircon.ReadAllRegisters()
                        Dim RoomTemps As Double() = PoKeys.GetTemperatures

                        If Aircon.SelectedRoom = Aircon.Rooms.EastWing Then         'we need to dump the netduino names for room numbers!

                            Dim ActualTemp As Double = Math.Round(RoomTemps(PoKeys.Sensors.Eastwing), 1)
                            .lblActualTemp.Text = ActualTemp.ToString("N1")

                        ElseIf Aircon.SelectedRoom = Aircon.Rooms.WestWing Then

                            Dim ActualTemp As Double = Math.Round(RoomTemps(PoKeys.Sensors.Westwing), 1)
                            .lblActualTemp.Text = ActualTemp.ToString("N1")

                        End If

                        Dim PowerState As Boolean = CBool(Registers(Aircon.Registers.Power))

                        If PowerState = True Then
                            .cmdAirconPower.Text = "ON"
                        ElseIf PowerState = False Then
                            .cmdAirconPower.Text = "OFF"
                        End If

                        '.lblFrontRun.Visible = NETDUINO.EastAirconRunning
                        '.lblBedRun.Visible = NETDUINO.WestAirconRunning

                        .lblSetpoint.Text = Registers(Aircon.Registers.SetPoint).ToString

                        Dim ExternalRef As Integer = Registers(Aircon.Registers.ExtTempRef)

                        If ExternalRef <> -32768 And Aircon.UseExtTempRef(Aircon.SelectedRoom) = True Then
                            .lblReturnPath.Text = ExternalRef.ToString
                            .lblRP.Text = "Reference Temp"
                            .lblRSoC.Visible = True
                            .lblOffset.Text = Aircon.Offset(Aircon.SelectedRoom).ToString
                        Else
                            '.lblReturnPath.Text = Registers(Aircon.Registers.ReturnAir).ToString
                            .lblReturnPath.Text = String.Empty
                            .lblRP.Text = String.Empty              'put these controls in a group and hide them all.
                            .lblRSoC.Visible = False
                            .lblOffset.Text = String.Empty
                        End If

                        Dim FanSpeedRadio As RadioButton
                        FanSpeedRadio = CType(.grpFanSpeed.Controls("radFanSpeed" & Registers(Aircon.Registers.FanSpeed).ToString), RadioButton)
                        FanSpeedRadio.Checked = True

                        Dim OpModeRadio As RadioButton
                        OpModeRadio = CType(.grpOperatingMode.Controls("radOpMode" & Registers(Aircon.Registers.Mode).ToString), RadioButton)
                        OpModeRadio.Checked = True

                        .ChkEconomyMode.Checked = CBool(Registers(Aircon.Registers.EconomyMode))
                        .chkExternalSensor.Checked = Aircon.UseExtTempRef(Aircon.SelectedRoom)

                        .lblSetpointMax.Text = Registers(Aircon.Registers.SetPointMax).ToString
                        .lblSetpointMin.Text = Registers(Aircon.Registers.SetPointMin).ToString

                    Catch ex As Exception

                        Debug.Print(ex.ToString)

                    End Try

                End If

            End With

        End If

    End Sub

    Shared Sub TimerStop()

        If AirconUpdateTimer IsNot Nothing Then AirconUpdateTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)

    End Sub

    Shared Sub TimerStart()

        If AirconUpdateTimer IsNot Nothing Then AirconUpdateTimer.Change(0, AIRCON_FORM_UPDATE_INT)

    End Sub

    Shared Sub TimerDispose()

        If AirconUpdateTimer IsNot Nothing Then
            AirconUpdateTimer.Dispose()
            AirconUpdateTimer = Nothing
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

---

I hope you get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve, I know it looks horrendous right now. But I'm a quick learner! :)

Happy New Year!

Comment: No need to lead questions with personal details - we're all just a bunch of pixels on a television screen here :)

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 ?

Comment: Do not use Thread.Sleep, use Await Task,Delay